# How to run the php file through cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to run a php file to store some set of values in database for every minute through cron job.
Here is my code to store the values in database:
store.php

```html
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass','sample') or die ('not connected');
$result = $db->query("insert into emaillist (email,fname,lname) values('ganesh@gmail.com','rathina','ganesh')");

?>
```

Normally the script ll run and the values ll be stored in the database.
but I need to store the values through cron jobs:
For crontab I created like this:

```html
01    *    *    *    * /usr/bin/php php -f /var/www/cronjob/store.php
```

But the file is not running.
What is the mistake I have done or what I have to do to run the file in crontab.

Answer (score 1):

`1****` will run one minute past every hour. `*****` will run every minute. That may be your problem?